# How to cite this document in APA style of citation

Tags: citations, apa

There is an online PDF document. It is issued by the Central Department of Statistics & Information (Saudi Arabia). The title of the document (42 pages long) is: Hajj Statistics. Year of publication is 2014. Pages referenced are 18-23. Since there is no individual author, can I consider the Department to be the Author?

What would be your APA citation for this entry? I'm not referring to the in-text citation, but to the one that would be listed in the list of references.

If this was an offline document, what would the citation be? What further info would be needed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Son of Citation machine is a very handy website:

http://www.citationmachine.net/apa/cite-a-website

You could try staring with auto-fill mode or do a manual entry and it will generate the appropriate citation for you.

Also - this is useful for reference:

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/10/

http://blog.apastyle.org/files/how-to-cite-something-you-found-on-a-website-in-apa-style---table-1.pdf